# How can i get cpu load in arduino?

Tags: arduino, cpu-usage, arduino-uno, cpu-registers

I wonder if **cpu load** can be obtained in arduino. Also, I have not found info about reading **RAM load**, although for *ROM load there is some information*.

Comment: I don't think the term cpu load makes sense on an arduino. It only makes sense if you use an operating system that is distributing computing time between tasks. In plain Arduino, you do not have this. you normally have 1 "task" and that is the main loop and it always takes 100% of the cpu load.

Comment: When you download your code I think the IDE displays percentage of static RAM usage (allocated). You'd need a SW tool to give you dynamic usage.

Comment: You need to understand the differences between CPU (that is used in a PC) and MCU(that is used in an Arduino), for MCU like Arduino, unlike in PC where code is loaded into the RAM to execute, it is run directly from the flash, and only data (i.e. variables, array, etc.) are loaded into the RAM.